# explain convergent using power series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, computational-mathematics

I want to use the power series of $(x+1)^{1/2}$ to explain why $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left({\sqrt{1+{1\over n}}-{1\over n}}\right).$$

converges. I was able to get the expansion of the series using binomial, how can I use that to show that the above series converge?

Comment: why don't you try a other method?

Comment: I dont think that what you wrote converge because $\sqrt(1+1/n)-1/n \to 1$

Comment: Did you want the $n$th term to be $\sqrt {1+1/n} - (1+ 1/(2n))?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't show that the series converges because it fails the divergence test. That may be why you aren't successful.

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}} - \frac{1}{n}\right) = 1  $$

Which implies that the series diverges.